# Retrofit - Keep Multiple Parameters for a Call but Pass Them as JsonObject Automatically

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

```
@PUT("edit/profile/{id}")
    Call<Boolean> editUserDetails(@Path("id") long id, @Body String firstName, @Body String lastName);
```

Above is a call withing a service. The server accepts JSON with the following format:

```
{
    "first_name":"xxx",
    "last_name":"xxx",
    "ncode":"xxx",
    "birthday":"xxx",
    "job":"xxx",
    "email":"xxx"
}
```

I found I need to pass a JsonObject as the only call's parameter, but I need to keep those parameters for the call to know what elements should be passed to the server. How can I keep those parameters, but pass a JsonObject finally?

Comment: keep those parameters as in ?

Comment: make a pojo and send using @Body annotation

Answer (score -1):

```
public class UserDetails {

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String ncode;
private String birthday;
private String job;
private String email;
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

public String getFirstName() {
return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getNcode() {
return ncode;
}

public void setNcode(String ncode) {
this.ncode = ncode;
}

public String getBirthday() {
return birthday;
}

public void setBirthday(String birthday) {
this.birthday = birthday;
}

public String getJob() {
return job;
}

public void setJob(String job) {
this.job = job;
}

public String getEmail() {
return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
this.email = email;
}

public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

}
```

Then make object of that class as:

```
UserDetails userDetails = new UserDetails();
```

then set values one by one as:

```
userDetails.setfirstName("xxx");
```

set other properties in this way too

Finally call it as:

```
@PUT("edit/profile/{id}")
        Call<Void> editUserDetails(@Path("id") long id,@Body UserDetails userDetails);
```

I think you want to know how to pass that jsonObject to retrofit call.Above solution is for that.If you want something else do let me know in comments.Happy Coding :)

Comment: Hope it helps you. Dont forget to mark post as answer if it helps you :)

Comment: I updated answer second way is better than first one. Go for it, this will work like a charm.